# Call action inside of component | React, Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've read this article (https://medium.com/@stowball/a-dummys-guide-to-redux-and-thunk-in-react-d8904a7005d3) a couple of times, but I'm still uncertain how to call your action inside of a component.

I've setup my actions and reducers correctly (I hope), so I'm at the last step now, which is using your action. I know that I first have to import my action and then use `connect` from redux to connect it to the store.

I currently have this in my component:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.serverRequest = axios
      .get('http://helloworld/customers')
      .then(res => {
        // Rerender state
        this.setState({
          res,
          dataToDisplay: res.data
        })
      })
  }
```

So my question is: How can I use my action inside of my component?

Answer (score 5):

As anything else you have to pass the action creator to your component via props. You can do this by using the react-redux library and the mapDispatchToProps function.

You will want to "bind" your action creator first by wrapping it in another function that calls dispatch on your action creator.

I highly recommend reading the following redux docs as it explains it rather well and also provides examples.

https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#implementing-container-components